# What are the common critical points of all Hitchin fibrations?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be an complex curve of genus at least two.  Fix some rank $n$ and degree $d$, and consider the moduli $M_{Dol}(C, r, d)$ of stable Higgs bundles of rank $n$ and degree $d$, and the Hitchin fibration $M_{Dol}(C, r, d) \to A$.  I am interested in its critical points, i.e. the points in the fibers where the fibers are singular.

In fact the $M_{Dol}(C, r, d)$ form a bundle with flat connection over the moduli space of curves $C$; i.e. you can identify the moduli of Higgs bundles as you vary $C$.

> Which critical points of the Hitchin fibration remain critical as you vary $C$ in moduli?

To state the question more invariantly, consider $M_{B}(C, r, d)$ the moduli of irreducible representations of $\pi_1(C \setminus c)$ with monodromy at $c$ given by the root of unity $\zeta_r^d$.  This space does not depend on the complex structure on $C$, and the aforementioned connection on moduli of Higgs bundles comes from the `nonabelian Hodge' diffeomorphism $M_B(C, r, d) \cong M_{Dol}(C, r, d)$.

> Which points of $M_B(C, r, d)$ are, for every complex structure on $C$, critical points for the Hitchin fibration $M_B(C, r, d) \cong M_{Dol}(C, r, d) \to A$

Let us call such points universally critical. Some such are given by the unitary local systems on $C$.  Indeed, these go to the Higgs bundles with zero Higgs field, which live in a nonreduced component of the central fiber of the Hitchin fibration.

> Are all universally critical points characterized in some analogous way?

I am also interested in the same questions with $G = GL_n$ replaced by an arbitrary reductive group.